# upgrading OkHttp3 library

Tags: android, react-native, okhttp

I'm using Okhttp:3.4.1 . Using this, all the https calls were giving

> java.net.protocolexception: expected ':status' header not present.

Some of blogs advised to update Okhttp. When I update from 3.4.1 to 3.10.0, I'm getting

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setCallWebSocket(Lokhttp3/Call;)V in class Lokhttp3/internal/Internal; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.Internal' appears in /data/app/com.XXXXXX.android-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes85.dex)
at okhttp3.ws.WebSocketCall.enqueue(WebSocketCall.java:108)
at com.facebook.react.devsupport.InspectorPackagerConnection$Connection.connect(InspectorPackagerConnection.java:243)
at com.facebook.react.devsupport.InspectorPackagerConnection.connect(InspectorPackagerConnection.java:44)
at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper$3.doInBackground(DevServerHelper.java:204)
at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper$3.doInBackground(DevServerHelper.java:200)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I'm using react-native:0.45.1

Comment: Is it happening on Android versions 16-20 and mostly Samsung devices by any chance? If so, then this is an open issue https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2372

Comment: @YogeshTelang No. it's happening across all the devices

Answer (score 0):

React native use okhttp as a dependency, upgrade okhttp may result in some compatibility issue. Currently it's using okhttp 3.6.0 (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/8466db0fd355aea778ff71cfb10c927cfd18a551/ReactAndroid/build.gradle#L288). So my advice is that just leave it be.

Comment: But, v3.4.1 is failing with https.

Comment: @M.Prabhakaran  Any proof to support your argument ? And If you use latest react native and you import okhttp 3.4.1, gradle will use 3.6.0 when resolve this. And we are using okhttp 3.6.0, find no problem with https.